# How to make a join return only one row based on minimum value of a column with same conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql, h2

Let say I need to do this:

```
select 
   * 
from 
   table1 
   left join table2 as tba on tba.column1 = table1.column1 and tba.column2 = 'A'
   left join table2 as tbb on tbb.column1 = table1.column1 and tbb.column2 = 'B'
   left join table2 as tbc on tbc.column1 = table1.column1 and tbc.column2 = 'C'
```

The only thing is that for each join on table2, it can return more than one row and I need to return only one row based on the minimum value of column3.

So what I need to do is something like this:

```
select 
   * 
from 
   table1 
   left join table2 as tba on tba.column1 = table1.column1 and tba.column2 = 'A' and tb2.colum3 has the less value from all the other with same conditions (tba.column1 = table1.column1 and tba.column2 = 'A')
   left join table2 as tbb on tbb.column1 = table1.column1 and tbb.column2 = 'B' and tb2.colum3 has the less value from all the other with same conditions (tba.column1 = table1.column1 and tba.column2 = 'B')
   left join table2 as tbc on tbc.column1 = table1.column1 and tbc.column2 = 'C' and tb2.colum3 has the less value from all the other with same conditions (tba.column1 = table1.column1 and tba.column2 = 'C')
```

How can I write this query?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a subquery, something like:

```
select * from table1 left join
(select column1, min(column3) from table2 where column2 = 'A' group by column1) tba on tba.column1 = table1.column1
```

You may try clubbing all three joins into one by adding `where column2 in ('A', 'B', 'C')`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the CASE statement, otherwise you won't be able to do get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up by doing a subquery.

```
left join table2 as tba on tba.column1 = table1.column1 and tba.column2 = 'A' and tba.colum3 = (select min(column3) from table2 wherecolumn1 = table1.column1 and column2 = 'A')
```